# Insufficient Storage - SD Card used as Internal Storage

Tags: google-play-store, external-sd, sd-card, insufficient-memory, internal-sd

I've formatted my SD card to be used as the internal storage on my LineageOS phone (Android 7.1 - HUAWEI Y5).

When I attempt to install anything from the play store I am unable to. Accessing the files through any file manager shows the SD card and Internal Storage merged as one (36GB total).

What can I do? Is there any application, Xposed module or Magisk module for this situation?

PS:Typed on my phone, hasn't been checked for grammar or spelling mistakes.

Comment: @Thally Ace It gives me the classic "uninstall an app to make space for this one"

Comment: And when sdcard is out leaving only internal storage. Does it give the error still about space?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What error does Google Play Store give. Insufficient storage? Or any other. And could 36GB be insufficient? Please note that application package rests on `/data/app` which is obviously internal, then all it's data is got in the sd. That means you may encounter that error if internal storage is below 15% of it's original size no matter how massive is your external sd. If that isn't still the issue, I think that's a bug in the Lineage OS you're running. I'm running lineage too. That feature works perfect like on any AOSP